# Error with watchify when trying to execute npm run watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, electron

Good day, i'm currently doing a tutorial on scotch.io where i'm trying to make a music player using electron and react, but when i try to execute 'npm run watch' i get this error message:

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 watch: `watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 watch script 'watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the electron-quick-start package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs electron-quick-start
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron-quick-start
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\music-player\npm-debug.log

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "watch": "watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.13.1",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.7",
    "electron-reload": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-sound": "^0.5.0",
    "soundmanager2": "^2.97.20150601-a"
  }
}
```

From what i've read in the tutorial browserify is supposed to come with watchify as well, however when i installed it as a separate module it worked but then i got the following error:

> console.error("SyntaxError: C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/Proyectos/music-player/app/app.js: Unexpected token (12:10) while parsing file: C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\music-player\app\app.js");

Answer (score 0):

I used the same tutorial, but I could not get everything working by applying the code snippets from the tutorial.

Do this instead:

- install both browserify and watchify:

  npm install -g browserify watchify
- clone the author's music player github repository instead of electron-quick-start. Then add or modify the tutorial code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it